# std::sync::Arc of trait in Rust

Tags: multithreading, rust, traits, rust-crates

I am trying to implement library for making TCP servers.

This is very simplified code with a problem:

```
#![crate_name="http_server2"]
#![crate_type="lib"]

use std::io::{TcpListener, Listener, Acceptor, TcpStream, IoResult, Reader, Writer};
use std::ops::Fn;
use std::sync::Arc;


pub trait Handler: Sized + Send {
    fn do_it(s: TcpStream) -> IoResult<()>;
}

fn serve(handler: Arc<Handler + Sized>) -> IoResult<()>
{
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 1234);

    for stream in try!(listener.listen()).incoming() {
        let stream = try!(stream);
        let handler = handler.clone();
        spawn(proc() {
            handler.do_it(stream);
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Compiler totally ignores my specifications of `Handler + Sized`. If I implement structure with trait Handler and try to call `serve` with this structure, such advice about size will be ignored too ( http://is.gd/OWs22i ).

```
<anon>:13:1: 25:2 error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `Handler+'static+Sized`
<anon>:13 fn serve(handler: Arc<Handler + Sized>) -> IoResult<()>
<anon>:14 {
<anon>:15     let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 1234);
<anon>:16 
<anon>:17     for stream in try!(listener.listen()).incoming() {
<anon>:18         let stream = try!(stream);
          ...
<anon>:13:1: 25:2 note: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` must be implemented because it is required by `alloc::arc::Arc`
<anon>:13 fn serve(handler: Arc<Handler + Sized>) -> IoResult<()>
<anon>:14 {
<anon>:15     let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 1234);
<anon>:16 
<anon>:17     for stream in try!(listener.listen()).incoming() {
<anon>:18         let stream = try!(stream);
          ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I implement one template function with multithreading that will accept different handlers?

Comment: [This thing](http://is.gd/uWHiqR) compiles fine, but dies cruelly. Likely, because you aren't allowed to do IO on the playpen. It runs fine on my box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment above,

```
use std::io::{TcpListener, Listener, Acceptor, TcpStream, IoResult, Writer};
use std::sync::Arc;

pub trait Handler: Sized + Send {
    fn do_it(&self, s: TcpStream) -> IoResult<()>;
}

fn serve<T: Handler + Sized + Send + Sync>(handler: Arc<T>) -> IoResult<()> {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1", 1234);
    for stream in try!(listener.listen()).incoming() {
        let stream = try!(stream);
        let handler = handler.clone();
        spawn(proc() { 
            let _ = handler.do_it(stream); 
        });
    }
    Ok(())
}

struct Hello {
    x: u32,
}

impl Handler for Hello {
    fn do_it(&self, mut s: TcpStream) -> IoResult<()> { s.write_le_u32(self.x) }
}

fn main() { 
    let s = Arc::new(Hello{x: 123,}); 
    let _ = serve(s); 
}
```

compiles fine. [(playpen)](http://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%2F%2F%23!%5Bcrate_name%3D%22http_server2%22%5D%0A%2F%2F%23!%5Bcrate_type%3D%22lib%22%5D%0Ause%20std%3A%3Aio%3A%3A%7BTcpListener%2C%20Listener%2C%20Acceptor%2C%20TcpStream%2C%20IoResult%2C%20Writer%7D%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Async%3A%3AArc%3B%0A%0Apub%20trait%20Handler%3A%20Sized%20%2B%20Send%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20do_it(%26self%2C%20s%3A%20TcpStream)%20-%3E%20IoResult%3C()%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20serve%3CT%3A%20Handler%20%2B%20Sized%20%2B%20Send%20%2B%20Sync%3E(handler%3A%20Arc%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20IoResult%3C()%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20listener%20%3D%20TcpListener%3A%3Abind(%22127.0.0.1%22%2C%201234)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20stream%20in%20try!(listener.listen()).incoming()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20stream%20%3D%20try!(stream)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20handler%20%3D%20handler.clone()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20spawn(proc()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20_%20%3D%20handler.do_it(stream)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20Ok(())%0A%7D%0A%0Astruct%20Hello%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20u32%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Handler%20for%20Hello%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20do_it(%26self%2C%20mut%20s%3A%20TcpStream)%20-%3E%20IoResult%3C()%3E%20%7B%20s.write_le_u32(self.x)%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20s%20%3D%20Arc%3A%3Anew(Hello%7Bx%3A%20123%2C%7D)%3B%20%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_%20%3D%20serve(s)%3B%20%0A%7D)

---

### Changes

1. Make `do_it` take `&self`.
2. Make `serve` generic, by adding a type parameter with the constraints you want.
3. Make the `impl` of `Handler` for `Hello` in `do_it` not discard the result of the write (remove `;`).
4. Clarify with `let _ = ...` that we intentionally discard a result.

You will not be able to execute it in the playpen though (`application terminated abnormally with signal 31 (Bad system call)`), as the playpen forbids IO (network IO in this case). It runs fine on my local box though.